# I have a asp.net .asmx webservice and I need to return a list of Address's that are closest to the client querying the webservice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, asmx

I currently have a webservice that I have built in visual basic as a asmx webservice in Visual Studio 2010.  Currently when I query the webservice with my android app I get a specified number of address's from the database.  What I need is for the Android app to pass along the users current location to the webservice and have it return a list of 10 of the closest address's in the database but how do I do this?

Below is the method I have that query's the database.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetFuelStops(ByVal skip As Integer, ByVal take As Integer) As FuelStop()
    Dim resultList = New List(Of FuelStop)()

    Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection()
        sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=***(***"
        Dim sql = <sql>
            SELECT
                [Physical_Address_Street]
                , [Physical_Address_Local]
                , [Physical_Address_State]
                , [Physical_Address_Zip]
                , [Phone_Number]
            FROM Gas_Stations
            WHERE Location_Type = 1
            </sql>

        Dim command As New SqlCommand()
        command.CommandText = CStr(sql)
        command.Connection = sqlCon
        sqlCon.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Dim fuelStop = New FuelStop()
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Street = reader.GetString(0)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Local = reader.GetString(1)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_State = reader.GetString(2)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Zip = reader.GetString(3)
                fuelStop.Phone_Number = reader.GetString(4)

                resultList.Add(fuelStop)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    Return resultList.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app needs to have GPS enabled(which will trigger the current location coordinates) i.e. Latitude and Longitude.

Meanwhile your database table should have latitude and longitude values for each address, as these latitude and longitude values will be used for distance comparison.

Once you have all your latitude/longitude values on hand, you need to use sin/cos formulas in the query to return the top 5 or top 10 records from your database.

Cheers